# copying files using Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, copy

This might seem like very basic stuff, but can somebody tell me what the purpose of this [0]; after the ("myfile3") in the code below does? I got it from the Google developers page but there is no explanation as to what it does. I am new to GAS and Javascript and don't have a lot of programming experience but all I am trying to do is copy a file on from my root drive in Google drive and then move it to another folder. Then code below works sometimes, but then after a while I get an error that tells me: "File copyFile must be converted to a Google document first. (line 5, file "copy")".

Any help appreciated. (Sorry if it is a stupid question)

The code is:

function copyFile()
    {

```
 var file = DocsList.find("myfile3")[0];
 var copy = file.makeCopy("myfile5"); 

}
```

Comment: you probably get errors because what you are copying is probably not what you think it is... see explanation below.

Answer (score 0):

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#find%28String%29)  : find(query) : Returns an array of all the files in the container **that contain the given string**.

`Find()` searches the content of all the files, not their names.

That means that you have to choose which element of the array you want to open... using `[0]` means you take the first result.
It might be the file you're looking for but it is not sure at all...

To narrow your search to the filename you should simply iterate the returned array while testing each file's name and pick up the one you want.
it might be in a for loop like this :

```
var files = DocsList.find("myfile3");
  for(var f=0;f<files.length;++f){if(files[f].getName()==query){var foundDocId=file[f].getId() ;  break}
```

From there use the file ID to access your file as this one is unique (names are not in Google Docs).

as simple as that ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Serge insas. As I mentioned in my question, I'm new to the whole area of javascript and google script so its good to get a nice, straight forward answer to my question. I'll probably have a lot of silly questions over the coming weeks. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest testing the DriveApp version of this function for two implicit reasons:

1. The DocsList service is deprecated and may be discontinued as the
   DriveApp functions are fleshed out.
2. DriveApp is a little more agnostic
   when it comes to filetypes, and may bypass your error.

Check out [fileMakeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy%28String%29) in the Apps Script Documents for details.